# Windows TFTP Server Recomendations?

Tags: windows, tftp

I am finding myself in need of a tftp server for a project. Can anyone recommend a good server for windows?

Thanks much,
D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[tftp32](http://tftpd32.jounin.net/)

Comment: you mean tftpd32 by jounin? If so I tried that one and it worked great for my needs.

Comment: tftp32 also doubles as a dhcp server! Quite handy.

Answer (score 2):

I've used [Solar Winds Free TFTP Server](http://www.solarwinds.com/products/freetools/free_tftp_server.aspx) in the past for testing and it's been fine.

Comment: This one runs as a windows service :)